# Массив PointF в массиве PointF C#

Tags: c#, массивы, winforms

Такая задача, нужно вычислить точки 6 треугольников, которые находятся на круге и записать их в массив которые хранит координаты каждого треугольника.
Не могу понять как записать все три точки, как один экземпляр класса PointF в массив triangles? Т.е мне надо чтобы triangles хранил в себе 6 points c координатами треугольников.

```
class Triangle
{
    float rad = 50;
    float rad2 = 80;
    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);
    PointF org = new PointF(100, 100);

    PointF[] points;
    public static PointF[] triangles = new PointF[6];

    public PointF CirclePoint(float radius, float angleInDegrees)
    {
        float x = (float)(radius * Math.Cos(angleInDegrees * Math.PI / 180F)) + org.X;
        float y = (float)(radius * Math.Sin(angleInDegrees * Math.PI / 180F)) + org.Y;
        return new PointF(x, y);
    }

    public void drawTriangle(Graphics canvas)
    {

        float ang1 = 0;

        PointF loc1 = PointF.Empty;
        PointF loc2 = PointF.Empty;
        PointF loc3 = PointF.Empty;


        Random random = new Random();
        int randomAngle = random.Next(20, 300);

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {

            float ang2 = ang1 + 15;
            float ang3 = ang2 + 15;

            loc1 = CirclePoint(rad, ang1);
            loc2 = CirclePoint(rad2, ang2);
            loc3 = CirclePoint(rad, ang3);

            points = new PointF[]
            {
             new PointF(loc1.X,loc1.Y),
             new PointF(loc2.X,loc2.Y),
             new PointF(loc3.X,loc3.Y),
            };

            triangles[i] = points;

            if (ang1 < 360) ang1 += randomAngle;
            else ang1 = 0;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Сделайте тип Triangle как массив из 3-х точек.

Comment: Что то вроде этого? 
public struct Trian{
            PointF xy1;
            PointF xy2;
            PointF xy3;
        }@becouse

Comment: Да. Тогда легко получите массив из любого количества треугольников.

Comment: я теперь не совсем могу понять как мне записывать мои loc в этот тип Trian @becouse

Comment: Trian ABC; ABC.xyz=loc1.